# Replace first occurence of first xml tag with different tag value which is present in environment variable

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I want to replace first occurence of xml tag value with different value. Values which comes from the environment variable from shell.

My environment values looks like TEMP1=ghi://1234 TEMP2=5678. So first value occurence has to replace with TEMP1 and TEMP2 by using sed/awk.

For example

```
<a>
  <value>abcd:efgh</value>
</a>
<b>
  <value>mnop:qrst</value>
</b>
```

Output :

```
<a>
  <value>ghi://1234:5678</value>
</a>
<b>
  <value>mnop:qrst</value>
</b>
```

Solution : It is not allowing me to replace environment variable.

```
sed -i '0,/<value>.*<\/value>/s//<value>$TEMP1:TEMP2<\/value>/' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: If you want to expand a variable, put the sed statement in double as opposed to single quotes

Comment: Double quote it doesn't worked. If environment variable contains forward slashes ghi://

Comment: Can you kindly suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expand variable, place the statement in double quotes. Also, as there are forward slashes in the text, change the separator to something else i.e. @ and so:

```
sed -i "0,/<value>.*<\/value>/s@@<value>$TEMP1:$TEMP2<\/value>@" inputfile.txt
```

Finally, you should really amend XML with a proper XML parser such as xmllint or xmlstarlet

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me.. We don't have additional package to install xmllint or xmlstarlet

Comment: OK. If you could kindly accept the answer also.